# Getting a form action error with AMP using .NET Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, amp-html

I'm getting the error

> The attribute 'action' may not appear in tag 'FORM [method=POST]'. (see https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-form)

When trying to validate AMP with Web Forms.

From reading the AMP documention, the `action-xhr` attribute is needed opposed to `action`. On this bit here: `<form method="post" action="./Default.aspx" id="form1" novalidate="" class="i-amphtml-form">`

Does anyone have experience in this / know how to change `action` to `action-xhr`?

Answer (score 0):

First, I haven't done this, so this is based *only* on a **quick** read of `amp-form` (the link you provided).

IMHO, end of day, you'll have to avoid `Web Forms` for your pages that you want to have an AMP form - the core mechanism of `Web Forms` is a `POST`back - which, just by the name, means a "form POST".

Mucking with that core functionality probably isn't worth the time, and if you did, you'll likely end up with:

A *separate `AMP` page* where you can do "bare bones" ASP.Net HTTP Request/Response scripting, or better (imho) Razor aka [`ASP.Net Web Pages`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/). Here's [a sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/4-working-with-forms) of what `Web Pages` looks like - of course you'll have to adapt it to AMP requirements in the link you provided.

You can then "tell" AMP clients (Google, etc) your `ASP.net Web Form` page has an `AMP` version:

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="https://www.example.com/url/to/amp/document.html">
```

REF: [Make your page discoverable](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/discovery)

Hope this gets you to the right path.